# VB.NET 2005 DataGridView Redraw

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

Description :

I'm using a Global DataGridView which is been created once , then I'm sharing that grid ByRef on multiple User controls  , the strange thing is ->  first control adding or Initializing that grid will draw it all others controls will not draw it  (For sure and I know why Its not drawing)

Question :  how can I force the global datagridview to redraw in every User Control that I have ..!!?

Mentioning that I'm populating the `DataGridView` Manully with out using data member / Data source .

Answer (score 1):

OK, that is really quite dangerous. Controls are not meant to be parented by multiple forms / controls. You would do much better to share the *data* (via an observable collection, such as `BindableList<T>`, or `DataView` if you are so inclined). Obviously this means setting the data-member/data-source, or doing all the updates (to all the grids) yourself.

But seriously; `DataGridView` (nor any other control AFAIK) is not meant to be used like that.

For info, *assuming* that VB's `ByRef` is comparable to C#'s `ref`, then you don't need that anyway... you are already only passing the reference (by value). But that isn't important since it won't work either way.